# CSS Fixing has unusual effect on browser window

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a sidebar that affixes in a way that is similar to http://thenextweb.com/

Here is a live demo of the bug: http://adamkochanowicz.com/static/build0502/kickstrap/_examples/contacts.html

To recreate the issue, just scroll down the page.

And somehow I managed to grab a screenshot of the issue:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod_object_assets/assets/4995413178034/grab_2013-04-12_a_3.00.59_PM.PNG?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJATICW4U3O4HFIEA&Expires=1367506772&Signature=DKQfG5DZSMHCzDO2BenbxpD2Zf0%3D

The grey area at the bottom is the "no-man's-land" you'd see when you scroll too far down on a page.

I'm using jQuery Waypoints to detect when to apply the `stuck` class to the sidebar.

Once the `.stuck` is applied, it gives `#sidebar` the following CSS:

```
section#sidebar.stuck {
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-color: #DDD;
  width: 25%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #eeeeee;
}
```

The jQuery is pretty simple:

```
<script>$('section#sidebar').waypoint('sticky');</script>
```

For some reason, this bug does not occur when the horizontal viewport is reduced. For example, when I open up the bottom-docked element inspector in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In contacts.html on line 866, your CSS line for the class '.row' looks as follows:

```
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Your bug is fixed once that is removed or set to:

```
.row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This works for you on http://adamkochanowicz.com/static/build0502/kickstrap/_examples/contacts.html ? I just tried it and it didn't work. If you're doing it in firebug or chrome's inspector, please close it after the values have been changed. It appears while the inspector is open, the problem goes away, so I think this may be a false positive.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Works for me even after I power down Firebug and Web Developer Extensions. Try removing that whole class altogether.